# Testing in-app billing

Tags: android, google-play

I've read quite a lot about in-app billing and testing but I still didn't find the answer to few questions:

How can I **test real purchases** on draft (unpublished) version of the app? The products/items need to be published => app need to be published. Is there a way to **publish items without publishing the app?**

The whole testing process is quite unfriendly to developers, shame on Google :(

I successfully tested my application using test static responses, now I need to test it on real items without publishing the application. The only way I can think of now is to publish the app for e.g. Kenya, publish the items, test and then un-publish the app.

Any ideas will be very appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I think I figured it out. All I needed to do was **publish the app and then unpublish**. After this I was be able to publish items and test real end-to-end purchases on these items. Very intuitive and developer-friendly :)

Answer (score 0):

No that'll be like selling stuff (your items) that you don't have the license to sell. (For e.g you need a pharmacy to sell drugs.)

I'm sure the people who wrote [this article](http://developer.android.com/guide/market/billing/billing_testing.html) must have considered your use case. From the article:

> You do not need to publish your application to do end-to-end testing. You only need to upload your application as a draft application to perform end-to-end testing.

Also I read this [here](http://developer.android.com/guide/market/billing/billing_admin.html#billing-catalog):

> An item's publishing state can be Published or Unpublished . To be visible to a user during checkout, an item's publishing state must be set to Published and the item's application must be published on Android Market.
>   .
>
> **Note**: This is not true for test accounts. An item is visible to a test account if the application is not published and the item is published. See Testing In-app Billing for more information.

Comment: I'm aware of that but if you read more you will find out that the item need to be published if you want to purchase it - even from the draft app. BUT you cannot publish item if the app is not published. And this is what are my questions about.

Comment: To your update - _"An item is visible to a test account if the application is not published and the item is published."_ I'm also aware of this, I really can read ;) But I didn't find any way how to accomplish this - to have app not published and item published. You can do that only if you have one apk published and other as draft. But I don't want to publish anything before testing.

Answer (score 0):

The products become published as soon as you publish the app.
And your app doesn't have to be published to do the real testing, just upload as "draft".
The app must be signed.

> The whole testing process is quite unfriendly to developers, shame on Google :(

Luckily there are libraries that can help with testing, for example [android test billing](http://code.google.com/p/android-test-billing/). This library is the In-App billing implementation for the emulator, which was tested in the application Horer [horaires de RER](http://www.horer.fr).